# psycopg2 copy_from--ignore header?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I can't seem to figure out how to simply ignore the header in a csv when using psycopg2.

Given the following csv sample, how would I ignore the top row as the column headers?:

```
this, is_is, a_a, test
abc,yes,yes,1
def,no,no,2
ghi,maybe,maybe,3
jkl,so,so,4
```

I can't tell if it's a parameter in the method or if it has to do with opening the file. Thanks.

Comment: is there necessary to using `psycopg2` , you can simply use `csv` module for this

Comment: You need copy_expert for that, not copy_from